# I'm looking for an algorithm to find all subsets of a set S with subset sums between a given min and max

Tags: algorithms, subset-sum

Given a set S of numbers, min and max. Find all sebsets of numbers from S with a subset sum larger or equal to min and smaller or equal to max.
The following article says that there's an algorithm called ESS that solves this but I haven't been able to find the algorithm anywhere:
"Cached Iterative Weakening for Optimal Multi-Way Number Partitioning"
https://ojs.aaai.org/index.php/AAAI/article/view/9122/8981

Comment: Are you aware that the problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard and that there are no known polynomial algorith?

Comment: For exponentially large min and max, @Nathaniel. For polynomially bounded, you can solve subset sum in polynomial time.

Answer (score 1):

For arbitrary min and max the problem is weakly NP-complete. Let min=max=W and the answer is "at least one" if and only if the original instance is a yes instance.

In any case, solve the problem using dynamic programming and count the number of solutions for each number in [min, max].

While actually outputting all sets will most surely take exponential time, you can count them much faster.